# Get last instance of derived class

Tags: grails, groovy, hql

I have two classes in my Grails application. One is derived from the other. Is there any way to easily get the last instance of the second class created for the first class. Please see example:

```
class korridor {

    String name
    String description

    static hasMany = [exceptions: Exception];
}

class Exception extends TerminKorridor{

    String type;

    static belongsTo = [terminKorridor: TerminKorridor]
}
```

I want to get the last exception created for a specific korridor.
Something like this: `terminKorridor.exceptions.getLast()`

Comment: You mean like `terminKorridor.exceptions[ -1 ]`

Comment: What does the "-1" mean?

Comment: The last index.  Or you could try: `terminKorridor.exceptions.last()`

Answer (score 0):

There is no "last"

`exceptions` in your case is a `Set`. A `Set` has no order. Change your collection type to a `List` in the `korridor` class and then it will have an order. Mind you this requires a schema change to store the index.

Here is the link to the section of the user guide that explains this http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps